# Check if a property exists on an object when the object may not exists either?

Tags: javascript

I can check if a property exists like so:

```
let myObject = {};
let exists = myObject.myProperty !== undefined;
```

But how can I check if the property exists when myObject is not defined either, the following errors:

```
// let myObject = {}; // do not set this
let exists = myObject.myProperty !== undefined;
```

Comment: Why not `let exists = myObject && myObject.myProperty !== undefined;`?

Comment: Why do you need to check property of no exist obj?

Comment: @Nitheesh [did you test that](https://jsfiddle.net/z8v257pc/)?

Comment: "May not exists" do you mean variable is not declared or the value might be undefined.

Comment: you must wrap the code with `try-catch/finally` if the variable might not exist at all, and then deal with it.

Comment: `try-catch/finally` is pretty big statement for just checking for property existence.

Comment: @koloml - The situation is not about checking for property but for accessing an *undefined variable* in the first-place.

Comment: @vsync that's true. But question title saying about checking for proeprty existence. I don't know why author not using something like `myObject && myObject.hasOwnProperty('myProperty')` instead of trying to access the object property.

Comment: @koloml you cannot do what you suggested without `try/catch`, it will throw an error (try yourself in your console...) Javascript disallows referencing *undeclared* variables and throws an error

Comment: Oh. Yes. I forgot about it. This will only work if I'll add `window` (or `global`) to check if this object exist in global scope. And this is usefull only if we trying to access something in this global scope but we not entirely sure if this object exist.

Answer (score 3):

There are several things at play here.
First, to check if the object exists in the current scope, you should use the typeof operator:

```
let objectExists = typeof myObject !== 'undefined'
```

this way, the interpreter won't throw an error.

Second, to check if the object has a specific property, it's still best to use the old `in` operator

```
let propertyExists = 'myProperty' in myObject
```

Both of these expressions return a boolean value, true or false.
So, for safe checking, you might use:

```
if(typeof myObject !== 'undefined' && myProperty in myObject) {
  // do your stuff
}
```

if you try to use the newer form of `myObject?.myProperty` it will still throw a ReferenceError if you haven't declared myObject

and if you use `myObject.hasOwnProperty(myProperty)` you might get a misleading result, if your object inherits from another and the property belongs to the ancestor

Comment: Small typo: `myProperty in myObject` should be `'myProperty' in myObject`.

Comment: you're absolutely right, thanks.

Comment: I like the ```let objectExists = typeof myObject !== 'undefined'``` thanks for this tip. also this is a neat answer

Comment: Did you forget the third check which OP started with (`myObject.myProperty !== undefined`) or are you removing it intentionally (and if so, why)?

Comment: @Flater I didn't. After interpreting his text, i assume he wants to know if the property exists or not, even if undefined

Answer (score 0):

if `myObject doesn't exist at all`, use `try/catch`

```
let exists;
try {
exists = myObject.hasOwnProperty('myProperty');

}catch(err){
console.log(err.message) 
}
```

if it's `null` or `undefined`, Use `?.` (optional chaining) operator:

```js
let exists = myObject?.hasOwnProperty('myProperty');
```

Comment: [Did you test this](https://jsfiddle.net/dp5ar3jb/)? Optional chaining is for checking to see if properties are available on objects _that already exists_.

Comment: @Andy I thought he means by ```doesnt exist``` it's null or undefined, but I see now. updated my answer

Comment: you copied my answer into yours... without improving anything... it's not nice

Comment: @vsync well, using try/catch the right answer now matter what comes after and we can disagree that my answer is more explanatory. plus you dont't need to hard code the error message since err.message already gives you 'variable is not defined`

Answer (score -1):

Since the `myObject` variable *might not* be defined (as per your question), you must wrap your code with try/catch in order for the flow not to break:

```js
let exists = false;

try{
  // try to access "a" property of myObject
  exists = myObject?.a;
}
catch{
  // because myObject is not defined, the catch block is invoked
  console.log("myObject", "is not defined")
}

console.log({exists})
```

Comment: you didn't explain why would he need ```?.``` inside the ```try``` or using the ```catch``` error instead of hard coded the error. update your answer if you really care about answering a question instead of reputation

Comment: OP does not need the catch at all, it is there for illustration-purposes only. Also, the `?` is explained by others already and thus needs no explanation since I dislike copy-pasting others code just so my own answer would have "everything". I am simply adding to the rest of the answers. No answer addressed `try/catch`, so I wrote it.